# How to match a pattern that repeats n times in a string using findall()?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a repetitive string and find multiple matches from it that match the pattern in my `findall()` function.

Essentially what I want to do is extract the names of the players from the string. They're separated by commas and the last name of the player is preceded by an "and". I tried to get the comma part down but for some reason `findall()` doesn't seem to repeat the matching pattern even though I added a `*`.

```python
x = re.findall('Players(?:\s([A-Z]+[a-z]+)),*', 'Players Jeremiah, Lou, Martha and Kay,')
```

I haven't gotten the `and` part down yet since I'm stuck on the commas but from the above code, I feel like, x should capture Jeremiah, Lou and Martha at the very least. My code only manages to capture Jeremiah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern starts with `Players...` hence it will only match once, because your string has only one `Players` in it.

This would be the correct pattern which also handles the `and` part:

- a player name is any character that is non-white space or comma,
- it must be followed either by a comma or white space + `and`

```python
import re

x = re.findall(r'([^\s,]+)(?:,|\s+and)',
               'Players Jeremiah, Lou, Martha and Kay,')

print(x)
```

Test run:

```
$ python3 dummy.py
['Jeremiah', 'Lou', 'Martha', 'Kay']
```

---

**Update** to match further sample sentences given by OP a single regex is no longer enough:

- match a mandatory prefix `Players` and extract the rest
- match an optional postfix, e.g. `are ...`, and strip that
- detect player names in the remaining sentence

  - starts at a word boundary
  - starts with an uppercase letter
  - followed by one-or-more lowercase letters
  - ends at a word boundary

```python
import re;

for input in (
        'Jeremiah, Lou, Martha and Kay,',
        'Players Jeremiah, Lou, Martha and Kay,',
        'The Players are Martha, Joe, Toby and Kay.',
        'The Players Martha, Joe and Toby are German.',
        'The Players Martha, Joe and Toby are German,',
    ):

    # strip mandatory prefix
    match = re.search('Players(.*)', input)
    if not match:
        continue
    #print(match[1])

    # strip optional postfix
    postfix = re.search('(.*)(?:\s+(?:are)\s+\S+[,.])$', match[1])
    if postfix:
        match = postfix
    #print(match[1])

    result = re.findall(r'(\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b)', match[1])
    print(input, '->', result)
```

Test run:

```
$ python3 dummy.py
Players Jeremiah, Lou, Martha and Kay, -> ['Jeremiah', 'Lou', 'Martha', 'Kay']
The Players are Martha, Joe, Toby and Kay. -> ['Martha', 'Joe', 'Toby', 'Kay']
The Players Martha, Joe and Toby are German. -> ['Martha', 'Joe', 'Toby']
The Players Martha, Joe and Toby are German, -> ['Martha', 'Joe', 'Toby']
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks! But the strings could be in different formats as well:

-"The Players are Martha, Joe, Toby and Kay."

- "The Players Martha, Joe and Toby are German."

Essentially, what condition would you use to filter them out? I think I could figure out the syntax myself.

Comment: That goes into the area of "natural language processing". A simple regex won't help there anymore.

Comment: I ended up implementing a far less efficient solution but this was insightful! I suppose this too rests on the assumption that the postfix will contain an "are" at the very least. My particular problem has the guarantee of not having any words where the first letters are capitalised besides the names, the "Players" prefix and a handful of special words. I used this to narrow down my results. 
Thanks a lot, Stefan!

Comment: If this helped then please remember [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're basically looking for a pattern for proper nouns. In the pattern you're using, it only captures "Jeremiah" because your pattern `'Players(?:\s([A-Z]+[a-z]+)),*'` specifically looks for a proper noun after the word "Players".

Please try this pattern instead:
`(?!^[A-Z]\w+)(?<![.]\s)([A-Z]\w+)`

It looks for proper nouns but exclude capitalized words at the beginning of the sentence.

> `([A-Z]\w+)` matches a capitalized word
>
> `(?<![.]\s)` ensures that we don't pick anything that follows a full-stop and a space
>
> `(?!^[A-Z]\w+)` leaves out capitalized words at the beginning of the string (in a new line for example)

**Warning**
A generalized pattern may not be ideal if you require 100% precision in your results. This pattern could potentially understate the number of names if your sentence begins with a name.

Test it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/A8Lagt/4)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What does '\b' do?

Comment: @investigate311 It's called a word boundary token. I hope you don't mind but here's the exact definition provided by regex101.com _Matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a character matched by \w and a character not matched by \w (in either order). It cannot be used to separate non words from words._

Comment: I guess essentially I want something that captures all the words where the first letter is capital. But what about the words that are capital because of they're at the beginning of the sentence? How do I filter those out specifically?

Comment: Thank you! I tinkered with the code here and used a variation of it for my solution! Thanks for all the help!